# IPV6 local UFW BLOCK syslog

Tags: syslog, ufw

The log in syslogs is as follows:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:e8:48:b8:5f:a0:e8:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:ea48:b8ff:fe5f:a0e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=52 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=16962 DPT=16962 LEN=12
```

What does it mean?

From what I found the IPV6 are local IPS, for what though? Should I do somethign about it?

Comment: i think it's an UPnP request. perhaps from some game program ? try to discover who has this ip6 `fe80:0000:0000:0000:ea48:b8ff:fe5f:a0e8` .

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I turned off both computers on the network and checked all phones' ipv6, no match. The requests come in every 20 seconds, all the time.

Comment: It does not respond to pings, I cannot check the list of ipv6 addresses given by the router, only range.

Comment: perhaps from an access point or the router itself?

Comment: Yes! it is from the router, found it. Allowing fe80::/10 in ufw should be fine? It stopped blocking the requests.

Comment: do you use upnp? if not it can be blocked.

Comment: Thanks. Just to check what it is and what it does: my router enables upnp on local network always, if i want i can enable it to dynamically open up ports based on what is needed, correct? If WAN upnp is disabled, it should be safe as long as no malicious device is on local network?

Comment: i prefer to keep it disabled on my lan.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it is a UPnP request from router.